# How to have a app have open and closed times

Tags: ios

So far I am working on a app that has open and closed times, like if I wanted it to be open different times each day of the week. And the times that is would not be open it would have a error message that says "We are now closed". So far all I have found is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-SW2) If you could help that would be great!!!

Comment: Your question is really vague and unclear. Do you mean an app the reports the operating hours of a business? So if you launched the app it would tell you if the business was open? Would you want to show the hours of operation as a table, or just "now open" or "now closed"? Would the data be stored in the app permanently, or would you be able to fetch new hours of operation from the business? And are you assuming that the user is in the same time zone as the business?

Comment: And what happens if the user leaves the app open during the time that the business changes from open to closed?

Comment: Oh, and what language do you want to work in? Swift or Objective-C? You should add the appropriate tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that gets the local time from the iOS device and call it in 'viewDidLoad'

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
     NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components: (NSCalendarUnitHour  | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:now];
     NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];

     if (hour > 6) {
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:@"The store is closed"];         
        }
  }
```

This very rough sketch would get the hour of the day and if it was later 6 display a message that the store is closed

Comment: This solution assumes that the user's device has its Timezone set to the same Timezone as the store.

Comment: Yes, in a fully fledged app you'd want to bear the timezone in mind and also probably build a whole new view including store hours etc, but I meant this just as a starting off point